# MySQL query to filter only expired users from table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export af list of subscribers from a database, and while my sql call works, it's missing some logic. My problem is - I want to export users with an expired membership. Some users might have both an expired membership and an active one. I don't want those users on my list.

I'm thinking I need a subquery to filter users with both an expired and an active membership, but I'm not sure how.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT 
jos_users.name,
jos_users.email,
jos_users.username,
jos_payplans_subscription.expiration_date,
jos_payplans_subscription.status,
jos_payplans_subscription.total,
jos_payplans_subscription.subscription_id
FROM jos_payplans_subscription
LEFT JOIN jos_users ON jos_payplans_subscription.user_id = jos_users.id
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_user ON jos_payplans_user.user_id = jos_users.id
WHERE (jos_payplans_subscription.expiration_date BETWEEN '2015-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-31 00:00:00')
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Does the jos_payplans_subscription.status not have a flag that determines whether they are active, expired etc?

Comment: Yes it does, but only for the current membership. A user can have multiple memberships, and I need to find only those users that have an expired membership and doesn't also have an active one.

Comment: Would you not be easier changing the schema.  For example a user can have 1 or more memberships and a membership can have 1 or more statuses (active or inactive).  Therefore create a many to many relationship between Users and Membership called "membershipStatus" where it has the composite PK of userID, membershipID and membership status?  This would give you a straightforward query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join back to the subscriptions table to find the active subs, and ignore those:

```
select q.name, q.email, q.username, q.expiration_date, q.status, q.total, q.subscription_id
from (
    SELECT 
    jos_users.name,
    jos_users.email,
    jos_users.username,
    jos_payplans_subscription.expiration_date,
    jos_payplans_subscription.status,
    jos_payplans_subscription.total,
    jos_payplans_subscription.subscription_id
    FROM jos_payplans_subscription
    LEFT JOIN jos_users ON jos_payplans_subscription.user_id = jos_users.id
    LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_user ON jos_payplans_user.user_id = jos_users.id
    WHERE (jos_payplans_subscription.expiration_date BETWEEN '2015-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-31 00:00:00')
) q
join jos_payplans_subscription s on s.user_id = q.user_id
group by q.name, q.email, q.username, q.expiration_date, q.status, q.total, q.subscription_id
having min(s.expiration_date) is not null;
```

**Edit:** Forgot the *is*

```
having min(s.expiration_date) not null
```

to

```
having min(s.expiration_date) is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort - but I can't get mysql to accept the last line - the NOT NULL part - throws an error on that. If I remove "not null" I get the same amount of users as in my initial query?

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing I've done before was create a junction table between a users and membership table called "activeMembership."  This had a composite PK of userID and membershipID and a column called "membershipSatus"

Then you could easily do:

```
SELECT username, email, membershipType, membershipStatus FROM
activeMembership
JOIN users on users.userID = activeMembership.userID
JOIN membership ON membership.membershipID = activeMembership.membershipID
WHERE membershipStatus='Inactive';
```

Maybe altering the schema and creating a many to many relationship would solve your problem?